# Https soap service in mule

Tags: mule

I have a requirement where soap based service needs to be consumed and in order to achieve that I had used WSConsumer component in Mule.
Where we give the service URL in the properties file and refer to it.

```
    <ws:consumer-config name="Web_Service_Consumer" wsdlLocation="serviceApi.wsdl" 
      service="serviceAPI" port="serviceApiSoap12Port" serviceAddress="${serviceurl}" 
      doc:name="Web Service Consumer"/>
```

Now after the development we came to know that QA web service is a HTTPS web service and while hitting the service following exception is received

```
SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
```

I'm able to hit the service with Http:request connector as following

```
<http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration" host="${host}" port="${port}"
        doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration" protocol="HTTPS">
        <tls:context>
            <tls:trust-store insecure="true" />
        </tls:context>
</http:request-config>
```

But the issue with above config is it won't work for HTTP configuration.
I should be able to connect to both HTTP & HTTPS as I have different environments.

Is there a way where I can achieve this with ws:consumer??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the HTTP connector configuration shown is the one queried by your WS Consumer connector. A simple solution would be to configure the `protocol` of your HTTP config via property file but Mule doesn't play well with it because you may end-up with a TLS Context configured with HTTP and your connector won't work. There is a little trick you can do however: create 2 HTTP configurations - one for HTTP and one for HTTPS:

```
<http:listener-config name="HTTPS_Config" 
    protocol="HTTPS"
    host="${host}" 
    port="${port}" 
    doc:name="HTTPS Config" >
    <tls:context>
        <tls:key-store type="${keystore.type}" 
            path="${keystore.path}" 
            keyPassword="${keystore.keyPassword}" 
            password="${keystore.password}"/>
    </tls:context>
</http:listener-config>
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Config"        
    host="${host}" 
    port="${port}" 
    doc:name="HTTP Config" >
</http:listener-config>
```

In a property file, define which configuration (i.e. which protocol) should be used:

```
host=localhost
port=443
protocol=HTTPS # or HTTP
```

And finally in your flow, use your property to reference the proper HTTP(S) config:

```
    <flow name="http-testFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="${protocol}_Config" path="/test" doc:name="HTTP"/>

        ...

    </flow>
```

The trick is to name your configuration `${protocol}_Config` such as `HTTP_Config` and `HTTPS_Config` so the proper one is used at runtime via `config-ref="${protocol}_Config"`. Mule will then dynamically use the proper configuration when your app is launched. This is entirely transparent for the user as only the protocol (HTTP vs. HTTPS) needs to be configured, and it can be used in any environment.

You can use this differently, the idea is to have Mule pick your HTTP or HTTPS dynamically at runtime.

EDIT: to configure your WS Consumer with HTTPS you'll need to reference a proper HTTP Requester Configuration such as:

```
<ws:consumer-config name="Web_Service_Consumer"
    ...
    connectorConfig="HTTP_Request_Configuration"/>

<http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration" 
    ...
    <tls:context>
         ...
    </tls:context>
    ...
    />
```

See [Web Service Consumer documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.9/web-service-consumer#using-basic-authentication-and-ssl) for details.

---

Note: though this solution works I would recommend using HTTPS *all the time*, for security reasons and to have less differences between your dev/QA/Prod/... environments - among other things.

I faced similar issues, we finally chose to have only an HTTPS config and define via property which keystore to use at runtime. In dev we would use a self-signed certificate and a proper keystore in environments requiring proper security.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Pierre, this would work if i'm using HTTP request connector, how do I achieve TLS in ws:consumer connector??

Comment: You need to configure your WS configuration to use HTTPS as well. I'll edit my asnwer with details